# How can I create 250 divs using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, for-loop

I want to make a website with 250 divs with their corresponding numbers in them. I could just type all of them, but I know I can use a for loop in jQuery. I am not really sure about how to go about doing this though. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: [jQuery Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/](http://api.jquery.com/)

Comment: What is your question? Your 3 points there seem to answer this already, just look up the functions you mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var container = document.getElementById('foo');
for (var i = 0; i < 250; i++){
  var d = document.createElement('div'); // <div>
  d.id = 'div' + i;                      // id="div{i}"
  d.className = 'someclass';             // class="someclass"
  container.appendChild(d);
}
```

Or, in terms of jQuery:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 250; i++){
  $('<div>',{           // <div>
    'id':'div'+i        // id="div{i}"
    'class':'someclass' // class="someclass"
  }).appendTo('#foo');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.  You'll need to replace  with the name of your containing div, and  with the name of the class that provides your common styling for them.

```
var c = $("#<container-name>");

for (var i = 1; i < 251; i++) {
  $("<div></div>").addClass("<class-name>").text(i).appendTo(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little ugly but using append once will out perform using it multiple times.

```
var html = '';

for (var i = 0; i < 250; i++) {
  html += '<div id="div' + i + '">' + i + '</div>';
}

$('#example').append(html);
```